How the extend the Gmail access token?
I am trying to create an add-on in which you can get a file from Drive or an attached document in a Gmail message and send it to my backend to scan it.
Drive is working perfectly, however I am having trouble with the access token from Gmail that is received as an event trigger. Receiving the token and using it is no issue, however I am having trouble with the add-on staying open for a while and when attempting to get the attached files, I get an error saying

Access denied: : Expired access token

Is there any way I can refresh or expand the lifetime of the Gmail access token?
Here is my manifest:
"addOns": {
    "drive": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "buildDriveWarningWindow",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "loadDrive"
      }
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "loadGmail"
        }
      ],
      "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
    }
}

And here is my loadGmail method:
function loadGmail(event) {
    setEnvironment(EnvironmentConstants.Gmail);
    setMessageId(event.gmail.messageId);
    setAccessToken(event.gmail.accessToken);

    return loadApp();
}

These are my set and get methods:
function setMessageId(messageId) {
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
        .setProperty(PropertyConstants.MessageId, messageId);
}

function getMessageId() {
    return PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
        .getProperty(PropertyConstants.MessageId);
}


And this is how I am attempting to get the files:
function getAttachmentsFromActiveEmail() {
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(getAccessToken());
    const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(getMessageId());
    const attachments = message.getAttachments();

    const availableDocuments = attachments.filter((attachment) => {
        const extension = getExtensionFromName(attachment.getName());
        return isAttachmentDocument(extension);
    });

    if (availableDocuments.length === 0) {
        throw new NoDocumentsFoundException()
    }
    return attachments;
}

I tried to refresh the token using the OAuth2 library provided by Google for Google Apps Script, however as stated in this documentation for google access tokens the token is not returned.
Screenshot of the documentation for Gmail access token:
If I cannot refresh the lifetime or get a new one without restarting the add-on is there possibly a way to extend the lifetime of the token in google cloud?

Every time the end user opens a specific email, you'll get a new access token for that email. Right?  How long does loadGmail take? Which line throws the error? How long after does it throw the error?


Yes every time the user opens a new email the add-on reloads and with that a new access token is sent.
The loadGmail usually takes couple of seconds ~2-3 to load, it doesn't take too much.
In the method getAttachmentsFromActiveEmail() the line  const message = GmailApp.getMessageById(getMessageId()); throws the error. Previously the token has to be set in the GmailApp because the getMessage uses a UrlFetch if I am not mistaken.
Usually about 10-15 minutes I haven't checked the duration exactly. The token expires and the error is thrown.


I'm not getting it: Why does it take 15 minutes before getAttachmentsFromActiveEmail is started?

I meant it takes about 15 minutes for the token to expire. Before the token expires everything works correctly. I apologize for any confusion.

I'm asking why does it take 15 minutes. Why don't you call getAttachmentsFromActiveEmail immediately when user opens the message?

I understand now, that is in the case if the user opens the add-on and starts using after it a while.

But as soon as the user opens, you get the token right. Just  use it right away without waiting for user to use it.
